# Python OptionMenu

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
varforoption = StringVar()
varforoption.set('a')
options = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
option = OptionMenu(variable = varforoption, options)
option.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

выдает ошибку `positional argument follows keyword argument`. Информации про `OptionMenu` в интернете очень мало, поэтому прошу помощи тут

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
option = OptionMenu(options, variable=varforoption)
```

В ошибке сказано, что `positional` аргументы идут после `keyword` аргументов. В питоне так нельзя.

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

Comment: `option = OptionMenu(root, options, variable=varforoption)`

Comment: tkinter сегодня пьяный. `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'variable'`

Comment: Не, это мы косячим)) `option = OptionMenu(root, varforoption, options)`

Comment: Наконец-таки заработало, спасибо!)